# Is there a way to add a pop up message that I can show to members who just joined my group in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I want to show a pop up message to every new user who joins my group. In popup message I want to show rules and regulations and a welcome note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to show popup message to a user who joins the group. For any new feature you can [request to Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/127103474099499).

Alternate option is (you may already know about this), you can post rules and regulations of the group and [pin the post](https://www.facebook.com/help/399494523452700). Pinned posts remain at the top until they're removed or unpinned.